# how to get a object that is in string inside the req.body in express?

Tags: node.js, express, backend, body-parser

I am trying to get the object from the frontend but the problem i am facing is that the fronend is sending that object in qoutes

```
Preview URL: false
[Object: null prototype] {
  name: 'Arun Teltia',
  email: 'acfsdzvff@gmail.com',
  message: 'test',
  'g-recaptcha-response': '',
  contact: 'contact'
}
```

here is the response i am getting i want to extract g-recaptcha-response in my backend how can i do that?

I tried to explain as much as i can and also i tried to search on google but i was not able to find something ,Thank you for the help in advance :D

Comment: Doesn't `req.body['g-recaptcha-response']` work?

Comment: @ffflabs i tried using this but it didnt work 
Edit: It worked sorry i am logging empty string and nothing was printing so i thought it dont work 
Thanks for the help :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **bracket notation** to access a property of an object:

```js
obj['g-recaptcha-response']
```

See [Property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors)